# c# Create various number of threads

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a method which creates different number of requests according to user's input. For each input I have to create an instance of an object and run method from that object in new thread.
It means I never know, how many threads I will need.
And later I will have to access data from each instance that I created before.

So the question is: How can I create different number of requests (and for each request one thread) according to user's input?

An example:

```
userInput = [start, end, start2, end2, start3, end3]

//for each pair Start-end create instance with unique name or make it other way accessible
Request req1 = new Request('start', 'end')
Request req2 = new Request('start2', 'end2')
Request req3 = new Request('start3', 'end3')

//create thread for each instance
Thread t1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(req1.GetResponse));
t1.Start();
Thread t2 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(req2.GetResponse));
t2.Start();
Thread t3 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(req3.GetResponse));
t3.Start();

//get data from each instance
string a = req1.result
string b = req2.result
string c = req3.result
```

Comment: Which version of .NET are you using? Sounds like a perfect job for TPL...

Comment: What is your question? You're not asking anything here.

Comment: I think loops might help you a lot.

Comment: VS2010 .NET4.0
Dismissile, my question is how to create threads that I need, because userInput can be different - 4 pairs Start-End, or 20 pairs, or more

Comment: SnowBear, that is what I have tried, but in that situation I don't know how to access result when method in thread is finished

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should NOT create a new thread per `Request`. Instead take advantage of the `ThreadPool`, either by using TPL, PLINQ or `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem`.

An example of how you could do it with PLINQ:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<Tuple<string, string>> Pair(this string[] source)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < source.Length; i += 2)
        {
            yield return Tuple.Create(source[i], source[i + 1]);
        }
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var userinput = "start, end, start2, end2, start3, end3, start4, end4";

        var responses = userinput 
                        .Replace(" ", string.Empty)
                        .Split(',')
                        .Pair()
                        .AsParallel()
                        .Select(x => new Request(x.Item1, x.Item2).GetResponse());

        foreach (var r in responses)
        {
            // do something with the response
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: Ebb, thank you so much, this is what I needed, but could you please tell me how to use threadpool in combination with that? Because this way (if I am right) new requests are made sequentionally not parallel

Comment: @PetrMares, No. The requests will run parallel, this is due to the nature of how `PLINQ` works. Under the covers, `PLINQ` use `TPL`, which uses the .NET ThreadPool as its default scheduler.

Comment: Then I don't understand, why for 10 tasks, it takes almost one minute to get results while with manually created threads only 20 secs. Is there some limit for number of threads in plinq? I am sorry for these questions, but I am new to to .NET4

Comment: @PetrMares, I'm not aware of how time consuming the operation you're talking about is. But `PLINQ` / `TPL` / `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` is in general only for *short-lived* operations. However in your scenario, it makes sense to use any of those three, because they *scale* - manually created threads don't. The reason for why the manually created threads are faster in your case, is that with 10 manually created threads the overhead of creation/destroying of a thread is not high enough to be slower than the ThreadPool. Try with ex. 100-200 operations, and the ThreadPool will win by far

Answer (score 2):

In .NET 4, this could be done via `Task<T>`.  Instead of making a thread, you'd write this as something like:

```
Request req1 = new Request("start", "end");
Task<string> task1 = req1.GetResponseAsync(); // Make GetResponse return Task<string>

// Later, when you need the results:
string a = task1.Result; // This will block until it's completed.
```

You'd then write the `GetRepsonseAsync` method something like:

```
public Task<string> GetRepsonseAsync()
{
     return Task.Factory.StartNew( () =>
     {
          return this.GetResponse(); // calls the synchronous version
     });
}
```

Comment: Thank you Reed, this is good hint, but I still don't know how to create those requests, because the amount  will be variable. Once it may be 3, but another time I will need 10

Comment: @PetrMares Just run this and make the Tasks in a loop.  You can make a collection of tasks, then loop through the results as needed...

Answer (score 1):

If you are using .NET 3.5 or lower you could use the [ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.queueuserworkitem.aspx) method and if you are using .NET 4.0 use the [TPL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx).